# Dbus-send другого пользователя linux

Tags: linux

у меня два пользователя `foo` и `foo-admin`, только у второго есть `sudo` права. 
Возможно ли и как, послать `dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.onboard.Onboard /org/onboard/Onboard/Keyboard org.onboard.Onboard.Keyboard.Show` из под sudo, пользователю `foo`?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, кто и с какими правами посылает, а кто принимает сообщение. В целом, сообщения принимаются и передаются по шине согласно выбранным правам на канал.

Comment: Посылать сообщение на чужую сессионную шину в любом случае плохая идея...